# jQuery .show() not working in this code

Tags: jquery

Here the console.log prints the JSON object. What is desired is the contents of the object be shown in the browser. That doesn't happen `entry.show();` is ignored.

```
revealed = 0;  
$('.order-table tbody tr').each(function() {
       var entry = $(this);

       if ( entry.is(':hidden') && revealed < 10) {
          entry.show();
          console.log(entry);
          revealed++;
         }
 });
```

The relevant HTML:

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
   <td style="vertical-align: top">
     <div style="float:left;margin-left:5px;">
     <table class="order-table changeLogs" id="bigTable" style="width:472px;" >
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Time</th>
     <th>User</th>
     <th>Field</th>
     <th>Original Value</th>
     <th>Changed To</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

```
  [% FOREACH changeLog IN PO.changeLogs %]
  <tr id="change_order_entries">
    <td>[%date.format(changeLog.ts, '%m/%d/%y   %l:%M %p')%]</td>
    <td>[%changeLog.nameFirst%] [%changeLog.nameLast%]</td>
    <td>[%changeLog.field%]</td>
    <td>[%changeLog.oldValue%]</td>
    <td>[%changeLog.newValue%]</td>
  </tr>
   [% END %]
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Can include `html` ?

Comment: You need to show your HTML and CSS too as they may be impacting this very simple code

Comment: Post your HTML or a reproducible JSFiddle

Answer (score 5):

Bug aside, you can do all that in one jQuery selector:

```
$('.order-table tbody tr:hidden:lt(10)').show();
```

Which basically says, find me all the hidden rows and select, at most, 9 (adjust the number to 11 if you wanted 10) then show those.

You should try to avoid using loads of code *if* appropriate selectors are available.

References

- https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

*Now if this does not avoid your bug, you need to show your HTML and CSS as it may be a styling conflict.*